# What is number of car parking spot ?

Tags: logical-deduction

[image].        What is the number of this car parking spot?

Answer (score 0):

> 87.
>  Just flip your the image upside down and it will make sense
>
>  [image: flip]

Comment: I prefer the answer L8.